# ld for Clang installation

Tags: c++, centos, clang

I installed CLang on CentOS using `sudo yum install clang`. Then tried using it by firing this command `clang++ main.cpp -o main`. This complained of missing ld.

Prior to this I had deleted the usr/bin/ld

I read that llvm has it's own linker; I am unable to find one. I also read that llvm lld was removed and the documentation says that one can make do with Clang only. Given that I have removed /usr/bin/ld, how do I get it back? Do I need to get it back? How do I make CLang use the linker that is supposed to be included with Clang?

I am debugging an issue and to one of the steps in trying to fix the issue was to reinstall the compiler, hence I resorted to deleting all the previously installed packaged and files, including ld.

Comment: `ld` usually is part of the `binutils` package, so you may try reinstalling it. Also, in my distro, `lld` is available as its own package, named just `lld`.

Comment: should I be using GCC/GNU linker with Clang? Or should I be using linker from Clang/LLVM toolchain?

Comment: Well, that is up to you. IMO, if you want to play safe, currently it is better to use the GNU linker, because that is the default configuration for most distros.